# How are these PHP function applied to a specific page in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm fairly new to PHP and trying to understand it practical ways.

I'm getting most of what's going on in the following code, with the help of http://www.php.net and http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/.

In its current situation, only one page on the site triggers the popup form if no cookie is set. Is that functionality specified within this code?

Here's the functions:

```
if (isset($_POST['confirm']) && isset($_POST['location'])) { 
    setcookie("Location", $_POST['location'], time()+3600);     
}
elseif (!isset($_COOKIE["Location"])) {
    setcookie("Location", "", 1);
}
elseif (isset($_POST['deny'])) {
    setcookie("Location", "", 1);
}

// Popup confirmation 
function show_popup($content) {
    global $post;
    $location = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'location', TRUE);
    if (strtolower($l) == strtolower($location) || strlen($location) == 0   
    || (isset($_COOKIE["Location"]) && strtolower($_COOKIE["Location"])  
    == strtolower($location))) {
        return $content;
    } else {
        ?>
        <div id="popup">
    <p>Foo.</p>
    <p>Yes/No?</p>
    <form action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF ?>" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="location" value="<?php echo $location; ?>" />
    <input type="submit" name="confirm" value="Yes" />
    <input type="submit" name="deny" value="No" />
    </form>
    </div>
        <?php
    }
}
add_filter('the_content', 'show_popup');

// Adds content to the <head> tag
function add_meta_content() {
if(isset($_POST['deny'])) {
?>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=<?php bloginfo ('wpurl') ?>">
<?php
}
if(isset($_POST['confirm'])) {
?>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=<?php echo $PHP_SELF; ?>">
<?php
}

}
add_action('wp_head', 'add_meta_content');
```

Comment: You used "understand", "paractical" and "wordpress" in the same sentence???? :-) Find the code for the `add_filter` and `add_action` functions. and read up on filters and actions and how they are used in the architecture of the system.

Comment: Haha. I wouldn't feel welcome on a coder's board if I didn't catch at least *some* sh!t for using WordPress. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's the if statement in the show_popup function.

It either returns $content (ie. does nothing) or outputs a form.

If the current post has a meta field called location that's not 0 characters long, and there's not a cookie matching that location, it will output the form.

Comment: Thanks, Peter,  for confirming the if statement. The thing I'm particularly interested in how a specific live page on the site prompts the form in the absence of a cookie when all the other pages do not. I'll update my questions to be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, it was the "location" custom field, https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/10457/how-are-these-php-functions-applied-to-a-specific-page-in-wordpress. Thanks to https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/2487/bainternet for the answer.